# python How to delete line from file

Tags: python

i was try to delete a line by his number 
example for the code

```
f = open("x.txt","r")
line = f.read()
f.close()
print line
```

the result is

```
test1
test
test2
test3
```

so now how I can delete test1 by line number 1 or any line in the file

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
def delete_lines(in_file, out_file, lines=None):
    with open(in_file) as f, open(out_file) as f1:
        for i,x in enumerate(f):
            if i+1 not in lines:
                f1.write(x)
delete_lines('in_file', 'out_file', [1])  # or you pass any line number
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this script you put the lines number in list and it delete them make sure to put the file in the same directory as the script:

```
f = open('1.txt',"r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open('1.txt',"w")
lines_del=[2,3]#the number of lines to be deleted
for number,line in enumerate(lines):
    if number+1 not in lines_del :
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```